# Filevault 2 not accepting any new passwords after recovery key unlock

Tags: passwords, osx-el-capitan, filevault, mac-pro

We use Dell Data Protection Encryption in conjunction with Filevault 2 on all of our Apple Devices at our office.

I have a user who was unable to log into her machine at the initial Filevault login with her domain credentials. We tried a bunch of her older passwords which did not work so we ended up generating a recovery key.

After entering the recovery key, we are provided with a "Change your password" screen. None of the new and unused passwords that we enter here are being accepted. The window will "shake" showing the password was not accepted.

[image]

One of our Mac admins stated that the limits are not set by the company but are password-length requirements from Filevault 2.

We have tried up to 15 character long passwords but we eventually hit a limit at ~20 characters.

The user is unable to log into her machine and none of the passwords are being accepted.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your Mac Administrators would better know what they have set the Filevault 2  password rules to be.on your infrastructure.  Hopefully, you have backups of all files contained within the profile, because there is a good chance they are gone.

Comment: I did end up getting the user back into her account after I posted this. I'm unsure if it was just a workaround or will end up being a permanent fix. Instead of entering a new password, I cancelled and entered my administrator credentials which allowed me to log into the admin account. I then logged out which brought me to the user login screen instead of the Filevault login screen. The user was able to log in normally from there.